# IJCADの起動オプション/LDを複数指定したときの動作について

Tags: ijcad

IJCAD 2018を使って開発しています。

IJCADの起動オプションはAutoCADと同じものが用意されてそこそこ動いているのですが、/LDオプション（モジュールのロード）を複数指定した場合、AutoCADでは複数ロードしてくれるのですが、IJCADでは最後に指定したモジュールしかロードされないようです。

これは不具合でしょうか？

Comment: 過去、あなたの質問への回答が一切承認されていません。解決済みであれば、承認をお願いします。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

これは不具合のようですね。

どうしても複数のモジュールをロードしたい場合は、/LDオプションに自動ロードする処理が入ったモジュールを指定し、その中でacrxDynamicLinker->loadModule(モジュール名)を呼び出せば、実現可能です。